# Maximize arccos-function

Tags: analysis, optimization

I need to find a maximum of the function

$$y=\arccos\left(\frac{29+12x\sin(22)+6x\cos(22)+x^2} {\sqrt{x^2+6x\cos(22)-20x\sin(22)+109}\sqrt{x^2+6x\cos(22)-4x\sin(22)+13)}} \right) $$

between x=0 and x=5.

However, WolframAlpha cannot find it and I haven't got access to a more sophisticated software solution e.g. Matlab or Mathematica. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Matlab is more sophisticated than Mathematica?

Comment: This really does beg the question; *why?*

Comment: Sounds more like a homework, if so label it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Just plot, and it and you'll see there is only one maximum in $[0,5]$

I guess if you take the derivative you will find that there is only a possible stationary point, and then checking the second derivative you would certify it is a maximum. But I guess in that interval the function is even strictly concave.[image]